# Cacti - How can you get a list of systems that meet certain criteria?

Tags: linux, monitoring, performance-monitoring, cacti

Is it possible using Cacti to have it give you a list of machines that meet a certain criteria?  For example, what are the machines that have had an average cpu load over 50% during the past week?  What machines have 5% free disk space?  etc. etc.

I haven't been able to find any suitable plugins, does anyone know of anything that can perform this task?

Answer (score 1):

[Threshold monitoring plugin for cacti](http://forums.cacti.net/about6344.html) is not exactly what you need but might help. More info about the Cacti Plugin Architecture [here](http://cactiusers.org/).

Comment: Marco, thanks for the comment.  I already use Nagios to handle alerts / thresholds like that.  I'm just looking for an easy way to see aggregate data.  

All I really need is a list of systems that match certain criteria.  If you have any other suggestions that would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Not a great cacti expert here, but as far as I know you can't do that "natively" in Cacti.
Also I don't know of a Cacti plugin that'll do what you want, but that doesn't mean there isn't one out there.

You could write a plugin that reads data from the cacti infrastructure and selects items of interest, or write something that'll fetch data from cacti (like you do with your browser) and parse the generated html.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using cacti for a few years now.  I've found reporting and summarising its data is very hard at the best of times.  Thold plugin is great for alerting but not to good on reports.  There is a [report plugin](http://www.kitefamily.co.uk/projects/cacti-plugins/wiki/Reports) for cacti that looks like it should do what you need, will require some patience though.